# Making an Employee List with variables. My code after compiling shows no output

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make a program where I am able to input information about "employees" and be able to manipulate the information I input through the code I have. 
If you look at the menu choices in my menu code, you'll see what I am trying to do specifically. 
I know that cases 5-8 have not been satisfied. But for now, I'm having trouble having an output of my code to test if the code works with what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
/*#include "mylib.h"*/

struct xrec
{
char name[11];
char ssn [12];
char g;
double age, hours, rate, salary;
};
typedef struct xrec Employee;

void printEmployee (Employee * a,int n);
double computeSalary (Employee * a, int n);
void printFemale (Employee * a, int n);
int displayMenu (void);
int search (Employee * a,int n, char * tssn);
void doSort (Employee * a, int n);
int main()
{
Employee temp;
Employee x[20];
char tssn[12];
int size =0, com , d,i;
FILE * infile;
infile = fopen ("Data.txt","r");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    printf("File Not found\n");
    exit (0);
}
while (fscanf(infile, "10s %s %c %lf %lf %lf",temp.name, temp.ssn,&temp.age,&temp.hours,&temp.rate) !=EOF)
{
    temp.name[10]='\0'; temp.ssn[11]='\0';
    x[size++] = temp;
}
fclose (infile);
computeSalary(&x[0],size);

do{
    com = displayMenu();

    switch(com)
    {
        case 1 : printEmployee (x,size); break;
        case 2 : printFemale (x,size); break;
        case 3 : printf("name:");
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (temp.name);
        printf("SSN:");
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (temp.ssn); fflush (stdin);
        printf("Gender:");
        scanf("%c",&temp.g);
        printf("Enter age, hours, rate:");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&temp.age,&temp.hours,&temp.rate);

            x[size++] = temp;
computeSalary (x,size);
            doSort (x,size);

            break;
            case 4 : printf ("Enter SSN:\n");
            fflush (stdin);
            gets(tssn);
                d = search (x,size, tssn);
                if(d < 0)
                {
                    printf("Student not in the List \n");
                }
                else{
                    x[d] = x [--size];
                }
                break;

                case 5 : doSort (x,size); break;
                case 8 : infile=fopen("data.txt","w");
                    for (i=0; i <size; i++)
                    {
                        fprintf(infile,"%10s %11s %c %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", x[i].name, x[i].ssn, x[i].g, x[i].age,x[i].hours,x[i].rate,x[i].salary);
                    }
                    fclose (infile);
                    printf ("File is Updated now...\n");

                    ;break;
                    default: ;
    }
}while (com !=8);


return 0;
}
void doSort (Employee * a, int n)
{
int i,j;Employee temp;
for (i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    for(j=i+1; j < n ; j++)
        if(strcmp(a[i].name,a[j].name)>0)
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
}

int displayMenu(void)
{
int c;
printf("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n");
printf("@ 1. List of Employee           @@@\n");
printf("@ 2. List of Female Employee    @@@\n");

printf("@ 3. Add Employee               @@@\n");
printf("@ 4. Delete Employee            @@@\n");
printf("@ 5. Employee Sorted By name    @@@\n");
printf("@ 6. Highest Salary             @@@\n");
printf("@ 7. Overtime Employee          @@@\n");
printf("@ 8. Exit                       @@@\n");
printf("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n");
printf("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n");
printf("Your Choice:");
scanf("%d",&c);
return c;
}

void printFemale (Employee * a, int n)
{
int i;
for(a[i].g='f';i < n;i++)
{
    printf("%-10s \n",a[i].name);
}
}

double computeSalary (Employee * a, int n)
{
int i;
double total;

for (i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    if ( a[i].hours <= 40){
        total = a[i].hours * a[i].rate;
    }else if (a[i].hours > 40){
        total = (a[i].rate*1.5) * a[i].hours;}
}
return total;
}


void printEmployee (Employee * a,int n)
{
int i;
double total;
for(i=0 ; i < n; i++)
{
    printf ("%-10s %11s %c %lf %lf %lf %lf \n",a[i].name, a[i].ssn,a[i].g, a[i].age, a[i].hours, a[i].rate, total);
}
}

int search(Employee * a,int n, char * tssn)
 {
 int i;
 for(i=0 ; i < n; i++)
     if(strcmp(a[i].ssn,tssn)==0)
         return i;

return -1;
  }
```

Comment: This could happen for an assortment of reasons (probably a segmentation fault before the first print). The most likely culprit is the fscanf but can be anywhere, I suggest to run it with a debugger (gdb) line by line and see where it falls.

Comment: @Aaron Nam Can you be more specific about the problem you are facing? You can put `printf` statements before `while (fscanf....` and `computeSalary` and so on (mainly before and after calling functions), then try to debug.

Comment: `fscanf(infile, "10s %s %c %lf %lf %lf",temp.name, temp.ssn,&temp.age,&temp.hours,&temp.rate)` : you forgot `&temp.g`